# Rails - DRY in Cucumber scenarios. What is a good balance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, dry

I have the following scenarios:

```
Scenario: Create a game with valid information
      Given I am logged in
      When I visit the new game page
      And I fill in "Game type" with "Basketball"
      And I fill in "Zip code" with "94040"
      And I fill in "Description" with "Friendly match"
      And I click on the button "Create Game"
      Then I should see "Awesome! Your game has been created."

Scenario: Create a game with missing information
      Given I am logged in
      When I visit the new game page
      And I fill in "Zip code" with "94040"
      And I fill in "Description" with "Friendly match"
      And I click on the button "Create Game"
      Then I should see "Game type can't be blank."
```

As you can see I am repeating code and as a **developer** point of view, I hate that I am repeating some sentences in both scenarios.  However, I assume that scenarios have to be independent clear, so any **stakeholder** can take a look and say..Oh, I know what this scenario is describing.

I am trying to test if my form validation is working correctly for different kind of field values.  So, I will have many similar scenarios that will be basically changing the "**fill in**" parts. So, another similar/related scenario would be the one that checks that zip code has to be numeric:

```
Scenario: Create a game with invalid zip code
          Given I am logged in
          When I visit the new game page
          And I fill in "Game type" with "Basketball"
          And I fill in "Zip code" with "ffff"
          And I fill in "Description" with "Friendly match"
          And I click on the button "Create Game"
          Then I should see "Zip code has to contain 5 digits."
```

So, my question is:  Is there any **DRY**, business people friendly way of doing this? I mean, a balance between code optimization and clear and understandable independent scenario definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [scenario outline](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines) would suit you well.